# Linked server permission for specific user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way that I change permission for linked server that user could not see linked server objects?

Actually I want to give access for linked server to specific user other should not show linked server objects.

Comment: my intentional currently is SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit your `linked server` to being visible only to one or some users.

If your linked server is already created and mapping is made, this will help you:

> When you create a linked or remote server, SQL Server creates a
>   default login mapping to the public server role. This means that by
>   default, all logins can view all linked and remote servers. To
>   restrict visibility to these servers, remove the default login mapping
>   by executing **sp_droplinkedsrvlogin** and specifying NULL for the
>   locallogin parameter.
>
> If the default login mapping is deleted, only users that have been
>   explicitly added as a linked login or remote login can view the linked
>   or remote servers for which they have a login.

[sys.servers (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms178530(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

If you set a new server, go to `security` tab, choose connections as "not be made" and add only a `login` that is supposed to reach `linked server`:

[image]

In my case I used `impersonation` as the same exact `login` exists on linked server but you can use any other mapping: uncheck "impersonate" and fill up "remote user" in case you want to map your `local login` to different login on `linked server`.